# c++ for loop does not terminate

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement

It might be quite a simple question, but my following code does not terminate, when I type in s for stop.

```
for ( roundNr = 1;roundNr <=3; roundNr++) {
    optiongame(roundNr);
    std::cout<<"Do you want to continue with the game? Press s for stop or press p for play \n";
    std::cin>> playstop;
    if (playstop == s) {
        break;
    }

}
```

Where: Optiongame is some function with different roundNr However, this works fine.
playstop is an input from the user about if he want to continue the optiongame or wants to stop. For that he can press P for play and s for stop

Could anyone help me with that? I would appreciate that

Comment: convert `if (playstop == s)` to `if (playstop == "s")`

Comment: You're comparing the user input to **variable** `s`. Unless the variable `s` happens to contain the character "s", it's not going to work.

Comment: Show your real code.

Comment: What is `playstop`? What is `s`? What do `optiongame` do? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And of course, [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in `if (playstop == s) {` I think there is any variable with name s in your code because this there wasn't any error because you are trying to compare variable with variable but you need to change compare variable value to  ‘s’:
try this:

```
s = 's';
for ( roundNr = 1;roundNr <=3; roundNr++) {
    optiongame(roundNr);
    std::cout<<"Do you want to continue with the game? Press s for stop or press p for play \n";
    std::cin>> playstop;
    if (playstop == s) {
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I have been unclear. But the " " where just for illustration in the question but not in the code. In the code i just have s

Comment: Then try to this `if (playstop == 's') {` it's not complete answer, can you show your variable definitions to further info?

Comment: Thanks! apparently that did the job! I defined `char playstop` and `char s`

Comment: then flag my answer as a answer ))